# Is there luggage storage at Poroy train station (Peru)?

Tags: luggage-storage, peru, train-stations, machu-picchu

[Peru Rail says](http://www.perurail.com/faq/#is-there-luggage-storage-at-the-stations):

> Is there luggage storage at the stations?
>
> Yes. Luggage storage is free at the Ollantaytambo and Machu Picchu
>   Stations, from 7 am to 7 pm for all PeruRail passengers.

However this year we are going on a family trip and I thought it easiest to leave from Poroy station.

Is there luggage storage there?

It's OK if it is not free, we just want to be free of luggage while going to and from Machu Picchu.

If there is not luggage storage there, where is the closest luggage facility to Poroy station?

Comment: I've tried messaging PeruRail's facebook page, but they didn't reply. I'd try calling them to find out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no official left-luggage facility at Poroy Station, presumably because there just isn't the demand for such "[All the hotels in Cusco & the Sacred Valley will store luggage for you if you stay there either before or after your visit to Machu Picchu, with no charge](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/ShowTopic-g294318-i3352-k7695533-For_all_those_people_who_want_to_bring_luggage_on_Peru_Rail-Machu_Picchu_Sacred_Valley_Cusc.html)".

It has been possible to drop off luggage at PeruRail's free facility in Ollantaytambo station en route to Machu Picchu and collect it again on the way back but this is not 'routine'. (There are 'STRICT' weight and quantity rules for the trains but these have *never* been enforced.) The normal arrangement is to leave it at a hotel, the nearest of which to Poroy are in Cuzco.

> where is the closest luggage facility to Poroy station?

And the nearest of these (as the crow flies) to Poroy Station (according to TripAdvisor) seems to be [Tocapu Boutique Hotel](http://www.tocapu.com.pe/main/en/home/) where a night's stay is around USD40. In connection with luggage comments on [TripAdvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Hotel_Review-g294314-d7688194-Reviews-Tocapu_Boutique_Hotel-Cusco_Cusco_Region.html/BackUrl#REVIEWS) include:

> 8 July 2016 The staff also stored our luggage during our trek.
>
> 23 November 2015  My wife and I stayed at Tocapu for 3 nights to acclimatize to Peru, then stored our luggage at Tocapu during our 4 day Inca Trek (free storage!).
>
> 9 July 2015 We were able to leave our luggage for a couple of days in the hotel while we went to other place in Peru.

In reality whichever hotel you choose to stay in in the area would make more sense to me, or if not staying in the area and arriving by air, somewhere in or nearer the airport.

Comment: Indeed, I can confirm this is the right answer. I was at the Peru Rail office last week and asked in person. The hotel solution worked as expected.